# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem with function argument

Tags: c#

I am using C# 2.0 and want to call a method with a couple of parameters with the help of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, so I tried as follows:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Multiply(2, 3)));

private int Multiply(int x,int y)
{
  int z=(x*y);
  return z;
}
```

I am getting compilation error. So please guide me, how can I call a function with multiple arguments with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`?.

I have another query that when I am using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` then how to use here anonymous function as a result I can write the code there instead of calling another function. If it is possible in C# v2.0 then please guide me with code.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should declare a method which have the same definition as WaitCallback delegate. You can use the following code snippet:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Multiply, new object[] { 2, 3 }); 

public static void Multiply(object state)
{
    object[] array = state as object[];
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(array[0]);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(array[1]);
}
```

Anonymous delegate version is:

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
    {
        object[] array = state as object[];
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(array[0]);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(array[1]);
    }
    , new object[] { 2, 3 });
```

Comment: i asked another things here how to use anonymous function along with  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. so i dont have to mention any method name. how to do it in c# v2.0.

Comment: @Thomas just define it in this way: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state) { }, new object[]{2,3});

Answer (score 25):

Using a lambda expression would also work

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Multiply(2,3));
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the lambda expression? i.e like the marked answer.
So i dont have to do all the object checking and casting within my method.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can do that without a Lambda expression. (you have to do explicit casts etc).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fuller example which gets the result back to the initial thread, and shows how the delegate can be defined anonymously:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MultiplyTask task = new MultiplyTask() { Multiplicands = new int[] { 2, 3 } })
        {
            WaitCallback cb = new WaitCallback(delegate(object x)
            {
                MultiplyTask theTask = x as MultiplyTask;
                theTask.Result = theTask.Multiplicands[0] * theTask.Multiplicands[1];
                theTask.Set();
            });
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(cb, task);

            Console.WriteLine("Calculating...");
            if (task.WaitOne(1000))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} times {1} equals {2}", task.Multiplicands[0], task.Multiplicands[1], task.Result);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Timed out waiting for multiplication task to finish");
            }
        }
    }

    private class MultiplyTask : EventWaitHandle
    {
        internal MultiplyTask() : base(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset) { }
        public int[] Multiplicands;
        public int Result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I needed an anonymous function. i.e., write to a stream asynchronously. So I used this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
    serializer.Serialize(this.stream);
    this.stream.Flush();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

for passing arguments without lambda - just pack all arguments into a class/object

```
MyArgumentsClass  m_MyArgumentsClass = new MyArgumentsClass();
 //fill arguments in class
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyFunction), m_MyArgumentsClass);
```

then, in the function - cast the object into your arguments class

```
public void MyFunction(object msg)
{
    MyArgumentsClass  m_MyArgumentsClass = (MyArgumentsClass)msg;
```