# Why some C# methods use an object to pass parameters instead of actually passing them directly?

Tags: c#, object, methods

I've seen some C# methods, like [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), that take a method ("WaitCallback" in this case) but instead of providing an option to directly pass arguments to the method, instead take a separate `Object` that can supply them.

So you can't do something like is being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564737/threadpool-queueuserworkitem-with-function-argument?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

My question is: Why?

There must be a technical reason to use this approach and not allow something like

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Multiply(2, 3)));

private int Multiply(int x,int y)
{
  int z=(x*y);
  return z;
}
```

Comment: `new WaitCallback(Multiply(2, 3))` would run `Multiply(2,3)` directly and give the result as the parameter to WaitCallback. Which isn't what you want - you need to send the arguments and the method to invoke separately so that it can be invoked on another thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you want to pass a *delegate* to `WaitCallBack`. In simple words, you want to tell `WaitCallBack` the method the thread has to execute, but you don't want to call that method *now*.

In your example

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Multiply(2, 3)));
```

the method `Multiply` would be called directly and its result should be passed to the `WaitCallback` constructor (which isn't possible).

There is no way for the compiler to decide if you wanted to **call** `Multiply` here or just want to tell `WaitCallback` that is has to do that call, because it would be totally the same syntax.

Thatswhy you tell it which *method* method it should call and - separatly - which argument it should pass when it eventually calls it.

---

But you could use a lambda instead:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Multiply(2, 3));
```

Now the thread can execute this lambda, which in turn calls `Multiply(2, 3)` (discarding the argument `o`).

Comment: So the lambda syntax would work? Still, if the C# creators are dedicated, can't they make it so that using `Multiply(2, 3)` in this "special" method would mark it NOT to be called right away but somehow "stored" to be used with these arguments in another thread, like passing an `Object` would?

Comment: @J.Doe: Ultimately, they *could*, but why would they? Wouldn't it make everything very confusing, if you'd have to know for each method call (i.e. the `a(b)` syntax) whether, in the particular situation the call appears in, the call is executed immediately or "stored", as you call it?

Comment: @J.Doe The lambda works. For the second question we would have to ask the c# team, but I don't see any benefit in such a feature, but a lot of trouble (and it probably would be a _breaking_ change, too). They _could_ build an implicit conversion (as the argument type is a delegate, the compiler _could_ convert the call to a lambda), but I think it would cause more trouble than it helps... even if you can make a clear distinction what the developer intended in the piece of code in question.

Comment: @RenéVogt, sorry, initially when I tried it said I had to wait and I forgot, since I subconsciously had accepted it as an answer. :)